# Convert a lot of .tif files using imagemagick's mogrify command

Tags: imagemagick, mogrify

I have a lot of tif images in a directory. So I try to convert them into jpg format.

I use this command : `mogrify -format jpg *.tif`

But I get an error... an error for each image in fact:

```
mogrify: 2281.tif: unknown field with tag 37724 (0x935c) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/746.
```

Maybe I am doing something wrong... Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: @Sardathrion i don't see how that's going to be useful to the OP. not saying you might not have a point, but i really don't get what you're talking about. mogrify *is* convert, just different syntax. consider adding more information to your comment?

Comment: `convert` (convert and modify images) vs `mogrify` (in-place batch processing) from the documentation.  I always used mogrify to change things in the images and convert to change the size/format.  Mogrify can be dangerous and lead to strangeness as described here: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#mogrify.  Sure, you can use mogrify and that's not a real answer the the question, thus a mere comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an informational error, are you sure that the file has been not converted?

http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=16390

Comment: Yep, I'm totally sure =)

Comment: Oh my god... I'm blind. The pictures are created... You have right ! So... I'ven't any bug. Sorry for annoying you ^^

Comment: If it's solved it's not annoying :-)

Answer (score 1):

That tag marks private information about the image for Adobe Photoshop. Try flattening the image before exporting/saving.