# Batch conversion of ".tif" images to ".jpg"

Tags: imagemagick, image-manipulation

I am using Manjaro GNU/Linux. I have a directory named `files`; under this directory, I have around 650 subdirectories with names such as `file1`, `file2`, `file3`, etc.

Under each subdirectory, there are between 2 and 11 `.tif` images.

I want to write a command or script to automatically convert all `.tif` images to `.jpeg` or `.jpg` so they remain in the same subdirectory and have the same name as before.

I know that there is the command:

```
convert source.tif ~/converted.jpg
```

Can you please help?

Thanks!

Comment: Consider https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/502963/117549 or https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29539/117549 or https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/144102/117549 or https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29869/117549, and probably others.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way of doing this would be with `find` executing a short in-line script that converts each found file with the `.tif` filename suffix:

```bash
find files/ -name '*.tif' -type f -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        convert "$pathname" "${pathname%.tif}.jpg"
    done' sh {} +
```

The in-line `sh -c` script above will be called by `find` with batches of found pathnames to regular files with the `.tif` suffix found under the `files` directory.  The `${pathname%.tif}.jpg` parameter substitution removes the suffix `.tif` from the value of `$pathname` and appends `.jpg` at the end.

Use `files/file*/` as the search paths instead of `files/` to look only in these ~650 subdirectories of `files` that start with the string `file`, ignoring any other subdirectory.

This leaves the `.tif` files in place, but you can remove them after successful conversion if you add `&& rm "$pathname"` after the `convert` command in the loop.

---

In the `zsh` shell, you could do away with `find` and instead rely on the shell's more advanced filename globbing and string manipulation capabilities:

```bash
for pathname in files/**/*.tif(D-.); do
    convert $pathname $pathname:r.jpg
done
```

Here, `files/**/*.tif(D-.)` will expand to a list of all the regular files that have names ending in `.tif` anywhere in or below the `files` directory.  The `(D-.)` at the end of the glob makes the globbing pattern only match regular files (possibly with "hidden" names).

The `:r` after `$pathname` gives you the "root" of the pathname (the name without the filename extension).

Use `files/file*/**/*.tif(D-.)` to restrict the search to only file in the `file*` subdirectories.

---

With the `bash` shell, you can do something similar to the above like so:

```bash
shopt -s dotglob failglob globstar
for pathname in files/**/*.tif; do
    convert "$pathname" "${pathname%.tif}.jpg"
done
```

The shell options set here enable the globbing of hidden names and the use of the `**` globbing operator.  It also makes non-matching patterns generate an error, just like by default in the `zsh` shell.

Answer (score 0):

With 7,000+ files you'll be there a long while doing them sequentially, so I would recommend taking advantage of today's multicore CPUs and using **GNU Parallel** to get them converted in parallel. Not only is it faster, it can also manipulate the suffix for you very simply and give you a progress report and do a dry-run to see what it would do without actually doing anything.

In `bash` that would look like this:

```
shopt -s failglob globstar
parallel --dry-run magick {} {.}.jpg ::: files/**/*.tif
```

**Output**

```
magick files/file1/1.tif files/file1/1.jpg
magick files/file2/1.tif files/file2/1.jpg
magick files/file1/2.tif files/file1/2.jpg
magick files/file2/2.tif files/file2/2.jpg
magick files/file3/1.tif files/file3/1.jpg
magick files/file3/2.tif files/file3/2.jpg
```

If that looks correct, remove the `--dry-run` and do it again for real.

---

If you have too many files and get an error, you can pipe the filenames into `magick` from `find`, and here I also add `--bar` for a progress bar:

```
find files -iname "*.tif" -print0 | parallel -0 --dry-run --bar magick {} {.}.jpg
```

Note that, unlike certain answers, this will also work if your TIFF files have an uppercase suffix.

Answer (score -1):

After you `cd` into the main directory containing the subfolders.

```
IFS=$'\n'
for i in $(find -type f -name "*tiff"); do 
    echo $i
    convert $i $i.jpg
done

find -type f -name "*tiff" -exec rm {} \;
```

`IFS`  is the internal field separator

The one problem i am seeing is that i was not able to extract the `basename` of the file

Dont forget to first try in a small folder before you move to big

Answer (score -1):

I would use a script similar to this one:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $# -gt 0 ]]
then
  if [[ -d $1 ]]
  then
    cd $1
  else
    echo "Given path leads to a file or the directory you are loking does not exist!"
    exit 1
  fi
fi
for dir in */
do
  echo "Changing directory to $dir"
  cd $dir
  for image in *
  do
    if [[ -f "$image" ]]
    then
      filename="${image%.*}"
      extension="${image##*.}"
      if [[ "$extension" =~ ^ti[f]{1,2}$ ]]; then
        echo "Converting $image to ${filename}.jpg"
        convert "$image" -compress JPEG -quality 50 "${filename}.jpg"
      fi
    fi
  done
  cd - > /dev/null
done
```

Setting up your script:

1. Save this as batchJPEGConvert.sh
2. Use `chmod 755 batchJPEGConvert.sh` command to make this file executable
3. Use `sudo cp batchJPEGConvert.sh /usr/local/bin` command to make this script accessible across your system

You can run this script by typing either `batchJPEGConvert.sh` or `batchJPEGConvert.sh path`. The first option will run this script in the current working directory. The other option will try to change the working directory to a given *path* and run the script there. This script will **only** convert files ending with .tiff or .tif extensions. It will also apply JPEG compression.

Note that this script only works for directories which structure is similar to this one:

```
test
├── 1
│   ├── polski.jpg
│   └── polski.tiff
└── 2
    ├── polski.jpg
    └── polski.tif
```